# What file system does Microsoft Reserved Partition contain?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, filesystems

## TL;DR

What file system does this partition contain? (NTFS, FAT32 or something else?)

---

## Story

Yesterday, I have used `ddrescue` to recover a slow and generally end-of-life hard disk drive.

The drive (WD 1TB) contains Windows 10, I don't know if upgraded from previous version or not.

There was but 1 single cluster, 4096 bytes in size, that contained URE (Unrecoverable read error), but somewhere in the beginning of the drive, which made one partition unreadable, I will mark the one below with *<-- THIS*:

The layout is readable from GNU/Linux Debian 9 as follows:

```
Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1        2048    2050047    2048000  1000M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sdb2     2050048    2582527     532480   260M EFI System
/dev/sdb3     2582528    3606527    1024000   500M Lenovo boot partition
/dev/sdb4     3606528    3868671     262144   128M Microsoft reserved    <-- THIS
/dev/sdb5     3868672 1902323711 1898455040 905.3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb6  1902323712 1953523711   51200000  24.4G Windows recovery environment
```

As you can see, it is [Microsoft Reserved Partition (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition).

**I intend to, at least, re-create the partition and the file system in it.**

But since I don't have any other Windows 10 computer at my disposal, I have a very simple question:

What file system does this partition contain? (NTFS, FAT32 or something else?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Final resolution of my problem

I **copied**, literally, the whole [**MSR partition**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition) **from a healthy drive** below, the partition was of the same size in sectors, also note a **GPT scheme**, it might very well be of importance.

Here's some healthy Windows 10 GPT installation, I managed to find:

```
Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1026047   1024000   500M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1026048   1288191    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3    1288192 459608774 458320583 218,6G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  459610112 461398015   1787904   873M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5  461398016 485992447  24594432  11,7G Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda6  485992448 488396799   2404352   1,2G Windows recovery environment
```

---

### Procedure in practice

I first backed up the bad partition for the case my efforts would cause more harm than good.

And then directly copied using [`pv` (man page)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv), you can always use [`dd` (man page)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dd) if you are used to it.

It was as simple as plugging both of the drives to my Debian server and using something like (intentionally upper-cased the letters to avoid anyone using that command and destroying something):

As `root`:

```
pv < /dev/sdA2 > /dev/sdB4
```

With `sudo`:

```
sudo sh -c 'pv < /dev/sdA2 > /dev/sdB4'
```

---

### Investigation

I could not mount the partition anyhow, and let me assure you I tried hard. At least I did try `cat`'ing it, some of it surprisingly makes sense, so I presume **it is there for a reason**:

```
cat /dev/sda2
```

```
RRaArrAa��U�U��X�MSDOS5.0 �?��@��)    ���NO NAME    FAT32   3ɎѼ�{���ٽ|�V@�N�V@�A��U�r��U�u
��t�F�-�V@�s�����f��@f�р�?������Af��f��f�F��~u9�~*w3f�Ff��
                                                                ����,����}��|�����t<�t   �������}���}��ߘ��f`�~� fjfPSfh�B�V@���fXfXfXfX�3f;F�r��*f3�f�Nf����f��f���v�֊V@����
�fa�t���f@Iu��BOOTMGR    
Disk error�
Press any key to restart
��U�RRaArrAa����U�U�
An operating system wasn't found. Try disconnecting any drives that don't
contain an operating system.�f�Ff�N$f��fFf�Vf�f�F�f�F�����f�F,f���G�f=������f��fF�������(�8-t�
                       V�m}��^t���;�r�Nu�fX�er������ ���u  �}��f����f����f��fF�������fX�����rЊV@� f���&f�f%���f=���ÿ~f�N
                                                         f3�f��f;F�t:f�F�fFf�Nf�f�^(��t:^�L�Rf��f�F$f��f�ZR�߹�>�Z���U���������������������OS        �V1Lr
```

---

### Conclusion

Without this partition, or in my case a damaged one, **Windows Update and a few other things did not work properly**, so the customer returned to me later on with this machine to fix these problems. I can report to you, **you can safely copy it from a healthy machine** in case of damage, supposing the same size and partition scheme.

It obviously contains **some data** without which Windows for whatever reason would not work properly.

Answer (score -2):

System Reserved partition is generally:

- of type NTFS

- around 100MB size

---

Some Microsoft Reserved partitions related to GPT disk are:

- of type UNFORMATTED

- often 128MB size

If someone decides to make a non-standard installation, the System Reserved can be just about any size. e.g., System Reserved will scale when people swap out the original install disk with something larger and use auto-scaling in the migration software. Some software is *dumb* and expands all partitions relative to the disk size difference.

---

You may find more info at [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions).